# Transfer App to my developer account in Play Store and App Store

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

OK, so my company hired some broke company to develope the company's app. They developed a version for Android and for iOS. They published both versions under their developer account.

The thing is they offer a very poor service, so we have decided to get our own Developer licencenses and design a new app internally.

Our idea is to make a deal with the broke company, so they transfer the app to our account. I've read there is a procedure for this in both stores:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en

My questions are:

- Once the app is transfered to our account, can we substitute our new app for the old one, so it stays under the same name and keeps download statistics (I don't really care about ratings).
- Is there any way the current app users can get an update notification linking to the new app if we don't have the old app's source code?

Comment: You're going to need their keystore if you want to substitute your app for theirs on the play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Apple App Store, this is entirely possible if they're willing to transfer the application to you (and the process is pretty simple!), but it appears you've already found that documentation. From a *user's* perspective, nothing changes; the app stays on their phone, and won't change at all. The next time *you* push an app update, even if the app has been entirely written behind the scenes, as long as you're publishing it to the same listing, users will receive the update as normal (App Store notification) and be none the wiser that ownership has changed. The only difference an end user would see is the "sold by" line in the store listing, if they checked.

I haven't tried the process on the Android Play Store, but from the description and the linked document, it appears the process would be the same. I mean, the link specifically says:

> When you transfer apps to a different account, your apps' users, download statistics, ratings and reviews, content ratings, and store listing information are all transferred to your new account.

So, it looks to me like you'll be all good. One thing to note, though: even though you intend to do what's in your users' best interests by making the app "better," they've come to expect the app in the way it is currently. If you completely change the app in a single pass, they may be pretty shocked and turned off to it. Be careful about dropping an entirely new experience on them without warning.

**Edit** Note on the Android link, there was also this to keep in mind:

> Our team can't transfer apps that offer subscription products.

If your app is subscription based, you may be out of luck on Android.